# What is the best design principle to add behavior in future to your API?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I'm designing an API. And, this API will be used by client.

Currently I've two behaviors in a class definition. To illustrate the scenario, sample implementation looks like the following-

```
public class Session {

    // instance field declaration goes here

    void connect() {
        // method definition goes here
    }

    void submitJob() {
        // method definition goes here
    }
}
```

I want to add more behaviors to this class definition in future to offer more functionality. And, I don't want the client code to change (i.e. My client will keep instantiating this single class and invoke behaviors as per their need.) But, I don't want to modify this class definition. Is there any design pattern and/or principle that can be followed to add behaviors to achieve the goal?

Note: I do not intend to add behaviors at runtime.

Appreciate any explanation and/or guides.

Comment: Adding is not a problem for an API, only changing existant is a problem.

Comment: @Spotted Adding is very much a problem for any API where implementations aren't controlled 100% by the API writer. It's become easier since the introduction of default methods in interfaces, but before that evolution of interfaces without breaking user code was impossible.

Comment: Related: [What design pattern for changing interface?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/266983/)

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing much about your actual structure and the behavioral changes you anticipate, I'd say, maybe the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) might be of help.

Basically, instead of declaring lots of different methods in your `Session` class and therefor changing its API all the time, you'd provide yourself a `Command` interface and all your actual commands, i.e. what actually needs to be done (and would otherwise be in different methods), go into concrete implementations of `Command`. Actually, it looks a bit like, your `submitJob` method is already on its way to receiving commands like those; just add a `Command` parameter... :-)

```
class Session {

    public void submitJob(JobCommand job) {
        job.execute();
    }
}

interface JobCommand {

    public void execute();
}
```

Comment: This is a guess but you'd probably also want to pass the current session to the command when executing.

Comment: @biziclop If the `Command` is passed into the session object via `submitJob()`, there's no need to pass the session again. :) Also, I don't really like passing state or session objects with (possibly huge) effect on the method's behavior since that method can get quite out of hand, possibly be unable to properly test (since the session could be in so many states or whatever). But I get where you're coming from.

Comment: I meant `job.execute(this);`, otherwise how would `job` know which session it's acting on?

Comment: Following my idea, it'd be `sessionObject.submitJob(myCommand)` since `submitJob()`belongs to `Session` and isn't static... Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Maybe, I'm confused now. :) What I meant was something like [this](http://pastebin.com/uEFFV478), imagine that session encapsulates an SQL connection for example.

Comment: Ahh, your session object implements two interfaces. Your `session.execute()` doesn't necessarily need `this` but any `Queryable`. It only gets `this` in your case since that object is implementing both `Session` and `Queryable`. I'd be careful with that design since it ties `Session` to something it doesn't need to be. I'd rather put some `Queryable`into the command itself and leave `submitJob()` parameter-less. But that highly depends on the actual problem at hand, I think.

Comment: Yes, my assumption was that session already encapsulates this querying behaviour (or some kind of behaviour that needs to be called by the command). If it doesn't, that's indeed a different story.

Answer (score 4):

## [Code against an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456424/what-do-programmers-mean-when-they-say-code-against-an-interface-not-an-objec)

`Session` isn't inheriting the 2 methods from an interface. Is it for the sake of brievity ? If not, you should always declare an API with an interface.

```
public interface Session {
    void connect();
    void submitJob();
} 

public class HttpSession implements Session {
    @Override
    public void connect(){

    }

    @Override
    public void submitJob() {

    }
}
```

## Evolution of your API

The fact that you methods don't take any parameters could block you in the future. Explanation:

```
Session session = SessionFactory.create();
session.connect();
```

The code above could be an exemple of the **current** use of you API. Maybe in the future you will see the need to accept a parameter *token* for `connect`. In this case you're screwed because you need to change your interface to

```
public interface Session {
    void connect(String token);
    void submitJob();
}
```

What if you need to add another parameter ? and change your interface to

```
public interface Session {
    void connect(String token, String username);
    void submitJob();
}
```

It seems you are screwed again and again...

To resolve that, one practice I already saw in API design **(disclaimer: I don't know if it's a good practice or not)** is that you add an object parameter to the method.

```
public interface Session {
    void connect(ConnectParameters params);
    void submitJob();
} 

public final class ConnectParameters {
    private final String token;
    private final String username;
    //TODO: add future parameters here

    ...
}
```

With this solution, you have a guarantee that the signature won't evolve and break your API.

Comment: It's funny to see how you focused more on the `connect()` method while I cared more about `submitJob()`. I fully agree with your `ConnectParameters` while I still like the Command pattern for additional methods. And yes, there should always be an interface, maybe even for your `ConnectParameters`, depending on how complex connection building may become.

Answer (score -2):

Just follow the SOLID design principles given by Uncle Bob along with OOP fundamental e.g. low coupling between module, high cohesion etc.

Comment: Yes, but *specifically*?